# Can anyone please help me prove these equations?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, binomial-theorem

> **Prove:—**
>
> $\log _{e}(n+1)-\log _{e} n=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^{2}}+\frac{1}{3 n^{3}}-\ldots$
>
> $\log _{e} n-\log _{e}(n-1)=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2 n^{2}}+\frac{1}{3 n^{3}}+\ldots$

*Here's my attempt:—*

> I know that,
>
> $e^{c y}=1+cy+\frac{c^{2} y^{2}}{2 !}+\frac{c^{3} y^{3}}{3 !}+\ldots$
>
> Putting $e^c=a$ I get,
>
> $a^{y}=1+y \log _{e} a+\frac{y^{2}\left(\log _{e} a\right)^{2}}{2 !}+\frac{y^{3}\left(\log _{e} a\right)^{3}}{3 !}+\ldots$
>
> Putting $1+n=a$,
>
> $(1+n)^{y}=1+y \log _{e}(1+n)+\frac{y^{2}}{2 !}\left\{\log _{e}(1+n)\right\}^{2}+\frac{y^{3}}{3 !}\left\{\log _{e}(1+n)\right\}^{3}+\ldots$
>
> By using Binomial Theorem, when $n<1$.
>
> $(1+n)^{y}=1+y n+\frac{y(y-1)}{2 !} n^{2}+\frac{y(y-1)(y-2)}{3 !} n^{3}+\ldots$
>
> In the above equation the coefficient of $y$ is
>
> $x+\frac{(-1)}{1 \cdot 2} x^{2}+\frac{(-1)(-2)}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3} x^{3}+\frac{(-1)(-2)(-3)}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4} x^{4}+\ldots$
>
> By comparing the coefficients of $y$ I get
>
> $\log _{e}(1+n)=n-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{n^{3}}{3}-\frac{n^{4}}{4}+\ldots$.
>
> Putting $n=a$
>
> $(n)^{y}=1+y \log _{e}(n)+\frac{y^{2}}{2 !}\left\{\log _{e}(n)\right\}^{2}+\frac{y^{3}}{3 !}\left\{\log _{e}(n)\right\}^{3}+\ldots$

**Now, here I am able to obtain the expansion (or series) of $\log _{e}(1+n)$ but I am not able to do the same for $\log _{e}(n)$ because I can't obtain the expansion of (n)^y.**

Also,

**By my attempt it seems like all these equations are applicable for only $n<1$**

So,

**Is there a more general/elegant proof applicable for all $n∈R$?**

Comment: $\log_e (n+1) - \log_e(n)=\log_e\left(\dfrac{n+1}n\right)=\log_e \left(1+\dfrac1n\right)$

Comment: apply the property of log $\log a-\log b=\log(\frac{a}{b})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $x=1/n$ into the Taylor series for $ \ln(x)$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln(1+x) = x-\frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots.
\end{eqnarray*}
and use
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln(ab) = \ln(a)+ \ln(b).
\end{eqnarray*}